# Why does my cout print twice?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a text-based game and want the player to choose single or multiplayer. I have the following check in my code:

```
cout << "Welcome to Hangman!\nIs this a [s]ingle or [m]ultiplayer game?\nGame mode: ";

int type = cin.get();
cin.clear();

//While input isn't single character s or m (either case)
while (type != 115 && type != 109 && type != 83 && type != 77) {
    cout << endl << "Please try again.\nGame mode: ";
    cin.clear();
    type = cin.get();
}
```

What's happening is if the player gives an invalid input, "Please try again. Game mode: " prints twice, but if the player just hits enter it prints once. I'm a beginner to C++ and read that cin.clear() sometimes fixes this issue, but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: `type` is probably new line character (<CR>) every other time.

Comment: `cin.clear()` only clears the error flags. There's still a `\n` from pressing enter in the stream.

Comment: Also, why don't you use character literals to compare to type? E.g. `type == 's'`

Comment: try to output the characters that you are getting from `cin`

Comment: (side note: what are those magic numbers 115, 109, 83, 77...? it isn't clear...:D)

Comment: Change first cin.Clear and add after second cin.get(): cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` after `cin.clear()`

```
cout << "Welcome to Hangman!\nIs this a [s]ingle or [m]ultiplayer game?\nGame mode: ";

int type = cin.get();
cin.clear();

//While input isn't single character s or m (either case)
while (type != 115 && type != 109 && type != 83 && type != 77) {
    cout << endl << "Please try again.\nGame mode: ";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    type = cin.get();
}
```

Edit: as dyp mentioned in comments `sync` is not guaranteed to do anything useful in this case (its behaviour is implementation defined) so the only portable way is to discard characters until new line